# Parsing a string containing # as separator

Tags: python, regex, list, parsing

Example string -

```
"{1#2#3,4#5#6,7#8#9,10#11#12}"
```

I want this as a 2D array/list.
like -

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12]
]
```

What is the most elegant way of doing this in python?

I have tried to split first on basis of ','. Then I get a list. for each item in lift, I split it on '#'. This way I can get it done.
But I want a clean way of doing it.

Comment: Wasn't me, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you are being downvoted because you haven't included in the post what efforts have you made.

Comment: Now that I have added the efforts put in, please upvote the question.

Comment: "The most elegant way" is opinionated. What's elegant to one person is deemed to be called 'unreadable' or 'obfuscated' by another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> s="{1#2#3,4#5#6,7#8#9,10#11#12}"
>>> list(map(lambda x:list(map(int, x.split('#'))), s.strip('{}').split(',')))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Here is what happens at each step:

```
>>> s
'{1#2#3,4#5#6,7#8#9,10#11#12}'
>>> s.strip('{}')
'1#2#3,4#5#6,7#8#9,10#11#12'
>>> s.strip('{}').split(',')
['1#2#3', '4#5#6', '7#8#9', '10#11#12']
>>> list(map(lambda x:x.split('#'), s.strip('{}').split(',')))
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['10', '11', '12']]
```

Comment: I think I would replace your `s[1:-1]` with `s.lstrip("{").rstrip("}")` which is more clear and safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "{1#2#3,4#5#6,7#8#9,10#11#12}"
print(list(map(str.split, s.strip("{}").replace("#"," ").split(",")))
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['10', '11', '12']]
```

Or a list comp and cast to int if you really want ints:

```
print([list(map(int,_s.split("#"))) for _s in  s.strip("{}").split(",")])
```

Answer (score 1):

Less noisy:

```
map(lambda x: map(int, x.split('#')), s.strip("{}").split(','))
```

Answer (score 1):

use a combination of `re` and `numpy`:

```
>>> import re
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = "{1#2#3,4#5#6,7#8#9,10#11#12}"
>>> digits = re.findall('\d+', s)
>>> rows = s.count(',') + 1
>>> np.array(digits, dtype=int).reshape(rows, len(digits)/rows)
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: You agree that this is a real overkill for this simple case, don't you?

Comment: @ByteCommander I think excessive slicing and splitting and mapping for this task is brittle and overkill.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the existing answers that use `map`, I propose a nested  list comprehension:

```
[[int(x) for x in row.split("#")] for row in s.strip("{}").split(',')]
```

Example usage:

```
s = "{1#2#3,4#5#6,7#8#9,10#11#12}"
l = [[int(x) for x in row.split("#")] for row in s.strip("{}").split(',')]
print(l)
# Output:  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

---

A slightly shorter alternative would be to combine both `map` and a list comprehension:

```
[list(map(int, row.split("#"))) for row in s.strip("{}").split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use a list comprehension:

```
[list(map(int, sub.split('#'))) for sub in s.strip('{}').split(',')]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't pay attention to that, it's updated now.

Answer (score 0):

This one is simple :)

## For

`s="{1#2#3,4#5#6,7#8#9,10#11#12}"`

`[el.split('#') for el in s[1:-1].split(',')]`

## you can get

[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['10', '11', '12']]